# "Everybody likes flowers, {don't they/doesn't he or she}?

Tags: tag-questions

Which is the correct answer?

> 1. Everybody likes flowers, **don't they?**
> 2. Everybody likes flowers, **doesn't he or she?**

Please explain.

Comment: I'd use the first one.

Comment: The explanation is that it's much simpler to use the all-purpose pronoun _they_ than to specify _he or she_.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tag question. If the subject is *nobody, somebody, everybody, no one, someone or everyone*, we use ***they*** in the tag.

> Nobody asked for me, did they?
>
> Nobody lives here, do they?

Comment: Nicely answered, very concise

Answer (score 0):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Everybody likes flowers, **don't they?** | Right |
| Everybody likes flowers, **doesn't he or she?** | Wrong |

Explanation:

The word "**Everybody**" represents a group of many people.
The word "*they*" is used when talking about a group of many things.

The word "*he*" is used when talking about only one person.
The word "*she*" is used when talking about only one person.

One of the following two things is grammatically correct if and only if the other is grammatically correct:

- Jack or Jill went down the the hill.
- Jack went down the hill or Jill went down the hill.

One of the following two things is grammatically correct if and only if the other is grammatically correct:

- "Jack or Jill" ✲ "went down the the hill".
- ("Jack" ✲ "went down the hill")  or ("Jill" ✲ "went down the hill").

The following two things have the same meaning:

- A ✲ (X or Y)
- (A ✲ X) or (A ✲ Y)

The following:

> Everybody likes flowers, doesn't he or she?

is grammatically correct if and only if both of the following are grammatically correct:

> Everybody likes flowers, doesn't he?
> Everybody likes flowers, doesn't she?

The problem is that "**she**" refers to one person.
"Everybody" refers to many different people.